# Replace plain URL with link if domain matches

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, hyperlink

Hi i would like to replace strings like this:

```
"Hey this is a link to somesite.co bye bye";
```

with

```
"Hey this is a link to <a href="somesite.co">somesite.co</a> bye bye";
```

**But only if somesite.co is found and NOT if it's someotherdunno.co domain**

What i tryed is to just split all the string and check each word, so that if domain is in the word i replace it with that

```
<a href="$domainFound">$domainFound</a>
```

But i don't like this solution i am sure there is some faster/better way to achieve this, do you have any clue?

thank you

Comment: Create a regex that matches `somesite.co` only. Then use string `replace` to replace the string with the href protion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use regex to replace and then append.

```
var str = "Hey this is a link to somesite.co bye bye";
str = str.replace(/(somesite\.co)/g, "<a href="$1">$1</a>");
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.outerHTML = str;
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

Comment: @sbaaaang waiting :) Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to find the known domains and then check if it's a valid url.

```
var i, len, re, domain, secure,
  string = 'Your string that contains my-domain.com !'
  domains = [ 'com', 'co' ];

for ( i = 0, len = domains.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    re = new RegExp( '(?:\\s|^)(\\S*?\\.'+ domains[ i ] +')(?:\\s|$)', 'g' );

    // find all possible domains in the string
    while( domain = re.exec( string ) ) {
        domain = domain[ 1 ];
        if ( checkDomain( domain ) ) {
            string = string.replace( domain, '<a href="'+ domain +'">'+ domain +'</a>' );
        }
    }
}

console.log( string );  
//Your string that contains <a href="my-domain.com">my-domain.com</a> !

function checkDomain ( domain ) {
    // returns true if the domain exists
    return true;
}
```

[**Try it on jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ktug702o/1/)